Meaning of 振り回す in this context
In Quintessential Quintuplets chapter 54, after the meeting with the father, one of the quintuplets apologized to Uesugi:

我が家の事情に振り回してしまって申し訳ありません

According to this post, I think this 振り回す means to manipulate Uesugi but I am not sure what is the function of に after 我が家の事情. I interpret 我が家の事情に either as "due to our family affairs" or "into our family affairs."

IMO the originally is grammatically incorrect. The correct way to write it is: 我が家の事情で振り回してしまって申し訳ありません.
The speaker is apologising to someone, because the circumstances of their family somehow forced the listener to be subjected to inconvenience/extra work or react to things leading to extra effort not once, but many times. The implication is that this was not intentional. Also it gives the nuance that this burden was chaotic, and especially changing in a contradicting way.
For example, say a couple have a divorce dispute going on, their parents might get 振り回される because they might had to bond when they got married, but now it's awkward and they might have to make adjustments (e.g. taking care of the grandkids, or not being able to see the grandkids as often etc. etc.). So they are burdened, and in a chaotic and especially contradicting/confusing way (once they had to become close, now they have to become apart etc.). This is referred to as  振り回される. Same for the couples' children as things change in unpredictable ways and they have to adjust, while experiencing emotional burden/confusion.
